# Search linux log files using mac terminal or script

Tags: linux, search, logging, directory

I want to search my access logs for traffic going to a directory on a Linux. I have a mac which I know I can do this with my terminal but I can't find an example how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the log locally on your Mac? Or are you asking how you would use a Mac to administer a Linux OS?

Open terminal, either change directory to the dir that contains the log or adjust the command to suit. Depending on what you want to search for, you'd use grep.

```
grep -i "dir name" logfile.log
```

It's a bit of a wide empty question so I don't know what you want to search for.

If it's remote, you'd open terminal and ssh to the server which has the log and do something similar to the above. Or, if you're asking how you would do it in one command, you could use ssh too.

```
ssh user@linux "grep something /var/log/apache/access.log"
```

Comment: I would login to the server and search  traffic logs for traffic going to a specific directory within the public html directory.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what you mean by grep something, but I will look that up.

Comment: Whatever the directory is, so grep -i "directory_name" access.log

Comment: Thanks I give it a shot.